# How to place a comma in the dictionary value (digits in this case )in the array received from an API in angularsjs

Tags: angularjs, format

I am receiving a data from an API which is a total number of places and the value is over 1000.
I want to add a comma after the first digit. How can I do that?
I have looked into the formatting of numbers in angularJS But the example on the website has number already added. In my case, I would not know what value I will be receiving as it changes but if it goes over 1000 I want to add comma there.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="test.html">

  <h3 ng-controller="TotalCooliosCtrl">Total Coolios: {{coolios.coolios}}</h3>
</script>
```

Angular:

```
    myApp.config(['$routeProvider',

function ($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider.when('/total', {
     templateUrl: 'test.html',
     controller: 'TotalCtrl'
    });
}])
.controller('TotalCtrl', function ($scope) {})
.controller('TotalPlacesCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://94.125.132.253:8001/gettotalplaces').success(function (data, status, headers) {
        $scope.places = data;
        console.log(data);
     })
})

.controller('TotalCooliosCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://94.125.132.253:8001/gettotalcoolios').success(function (data, status, headers) {
    $scope.coolios = data;
    console.log(data);
})
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a filter, and the Number filter already exists, here is the link :https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

In you case, I think the following code should work:

```
<h3 ng-controller="TotalCooliosCtrl">Total Coolios: {{coolios.coolios | number}}</h3>
```

Comment: How would I add a comma in there? will it do that if i put number in there? e.g. $filter('data')(number)

Comment: As explained in the doc number is a pre-existing filter in Angular, to apply it in the controller (assuming that your variable is called 'data'), you should do the opposite : data = $filter('number')(data)

Comment: I didnt need the filter it worked with | number only

Comment: In fact this is the same but the | notation works in the view (your html) and $filter()() works inside your controller, but the result is the same !